# Java JDK 11 version compatibility with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, openjfx

Can higher version of openjfx works with lower version jdk? For example I want to use AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.6 and OpenJFX 13.0.2 together, is it possible/advisable to do so?

Comment: Did you try it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [release notes](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/doc-files/release-notes-13.md) of java fx 13 it says:

> JavaFX 13 requires JDK 11 or later.

Comment: https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/doc-files/release-notes-13.md